# EFCore How do two relation tables have a navigation each other?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have following models.

```cs
public class Blog
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [NotMapped]
  public List<int> FileIds
  {
    get
    {
      if (FileIdsJSON == nul) return null;
      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(FileIdsJSON);
    }

    set
    {
      FileIdsJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); // Like [1,4,5,2] - Includes orders of the Ids.
    }
  }
  public string FileIdsJSON { get; set; };
  [ForeignKey("MenuFileId")]
  public File MenuFile { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("ThumbnailFileId")]
  public File ThumbnailFile { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Uri { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
  public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Blog and File Relation: 1:N

Blog have three columns that point to File 'ThumbnailFileId', 'MenuFileId', 'FileIds'. And We know whether File is thumbnail or menu file or others from what accessing a column.

Like below.

```cs
var blog = context.Blog.Find(/**some id*//);
// blog.ThumbnailFile.Uri
// blog.MenuFile.Uri
// context.File.Find(blog.FileIds[0]).Uri
```

Validation of integrity of FileIds is performed by backend code side.

We must have to be can search Blog by File and search File By Blog.

So, I wrote code like above. but It doesn't work.

How should I implement this?

Comment: `[ForeignKey("MenuFileId")]` -- I do not see a MenuFileId defined in Blog.

Comment: @SteveGreene I edited. Now, Blog has two params MenuFileId and ThumbnailFileId.